# How to make element fade in on page scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, css, opacity, onscroll

I have the following element in my page:

```
<div id="banner" class="disappear">Hello</div>
```

The CSS for this element is:

```
#banner {position:fixed;}
.disappear {opacity:0;}
.appear {opacity:1;}`
```

I'd like to know how to change the class from `.disappear` to `.appear` with jQuery when the page scrolls to a certain point, and then back to `.disappear` when the page returns to original position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out jQuery [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/).

Using this plugin, you could do something like this:

```
<div id="banner">Hello</div>
```

And your jQuery:

```
$("#banner").waypoint(function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(750);
},{
    offset: 'bottom-in-view'
});
```

Comment: thanks!  Waypoints is just what I was looking for!   I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't make a full working example.  But you'll need to use `$(window).scroll(function(){` to execute every time the window scrolls.  Then in that function you will need to check `$(window).scrollTop()` to determine how far the user has scrolled.

http://jsfiddle.net/s8dhy/

Then based on that value, you will add and remove classes or `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.  The title says you want "fade" in which case you'll want to use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.  If you do just want to add and remove a class, then use `addClass` and `removeClass`.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I'll try out Purmou's suggestion, as I'm not that well versed in JS, but I can follow instructions :)